# spring security and spring session, avoid creating sessions for request without x-auth-token header

Tags: spring-security, spring-session

I using Spring session rest and spring security, each request should has header "x-auth-token" whose value is session id. But for those request without that header (such as options method), it stills create session. How to avoid this?

(Currently I add a listener for session event and delete those unauthorized session)
Here is my primary configuration:

spring session config:

```
@Configuration
@EnableHazelcastHttpSession(maxInactiveIntervalInSeconds = 86400)
public class JxSessionConfig {

    @Bean
    public HazelcastInstance hazelcastInstance() {
        MapAttributeConfig attributeConfig = new MapAttributeConfig()
                .setName(HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE)
                .setExtractor(PrincipalNameExtractor.class.getName());

        Config config = new Config();

        config.getMapConfig("spring:session:sessions")
                .addMapAttributeConfig(attributeConfig)
                .addMapIndexConfig(new MapIndexConfig(
                        HazelcastSessionRepository.PRINCIPAL_NAME_ATTRIBUTE, false));

        return Hazelcast.newHazelcastInstance(config);
    }
    @Bean
    public HttpSessionStrategy httpSessionStrategy() {
        return new HeaderHttpSessionStrategy();
    }

   /* //直接在session配置类中注入listener的bean即可监听事件
    @Bean
    public HttpSessionListener httpSessionListener() {
        return new JxSessionListener();
    }*/
}
```

spring security config:

```
@Override
  protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
  httpSecurity
  .csrf().disable()
  .exceptionHandling().authenticationEntryPoint(unauthorizedHandler).and() 
  .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.ALWAYS).and()  
  .headers().frameOptions().sameOrigin().and()

  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS).permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/anon/**").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/token/**").permitAll()
  .antMatchers("/rest/**").hasRole("USER")

  httpSecurity
  .addFilter(authenticationTokenFilterBean());
  // disable page caching
  httpSecurity.headers().cacheControl();
  httpSecurity.requestCache().requestCache(new NullRequestCache());
  httpSecurity.formLogin().failureHandler(authenticationFailureHandler());
  httpSecurity.rememberMe();
  }

  private AuthenticationFailureHandler authenticationFailureHandler() {
  return new AuthenticationFailureHandler();
  }

  public class AuthenticationFailureHandler
  extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationFailureHandler {
  }
```

Apologize for poor English and your response is highly appreciated^_^

Comment: Thanks,I have already use other policy and I find the reason just now after many times try!!  request cache is not useful before .anyRequest().authenticated() so those .antMatchers if need authentication it still create session. I find the reasons but no method to resolve it

Comment: no, I need use NullRequestCache but it is only useful for request need roles, and has no effect on  permitAll request

Comment: I have the same problem too, and im ussing the "never" policy. did you find a way to solve this?